# Fatal Error installing opencart on local server

Tags: opencart

```
Warning: require_once(/websites/xxxx/system/startup.php): failed to open stream: 
No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\websites\xxxx\index.php on line 21

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/websites/xxxx/system/startup.php' 
(include_path='.;D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\xampp\htdocs\websites\xxxx\index.php on line 21
```

Answer (score 0):

check local server paths in config.php and admin/config.php

Suggests you have a problem with your config files. Check both your config files (config.php and admin/config.php) and make sure that the defined path for "DIR_SYSTEM" has a closing "/" at the end of it, eg.:

```
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/xxxx/public_html/shop/system/');
```